# bower to use http instead of https

Tags: http, https, npm, bower

Is there a way to force bower install to use http instead of https? I was able to resolve this in npm by **npm config set strict-ssl false**. I'd like to know if there is a bower command that I can run to disable ssl. THanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add or edit either your user or project specific `.bowerrc` file and add the following configuration.

```
{
  "strict-ssl": false
}
```

This works exactly like `strict-ssl false` in the npm config file.

Comment: Surprising that this post isn't more popular